# ReactNative MQTT Listener

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have the following code excerpt:

```
client.on ('message', function (msg) {
// ....
});
```

Can someone tell me how I get the value of msg from this function and can access it from outside.
I tried but it doesn't work:

```
this.setState ({msg: msg})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an `MQTT manager` and use it.

**Example**

```js
module.exports = {  // cached singleton instance
  QOS: 1, // Only 0 and 1 supported by Rabbit
  props: null,
 create(userID, connectionProps = {}) {
    if (userID && connectionProps) {
      // http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/
      this.onConnectionOpened = this.onConnectionOpened.bind(this);
      this.onConnectionClosed = this.onConnectionClosed.bind(this);
      this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);
      this.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived.bind(this);
      this.disconnect = this.disconnect.bind(this);

      const deviceId = this.randIdCreator()
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '');

      this.conProps = _.extend({
        clientId: `realtime.${userID}.${deviceId}`,
        channelToUse: `mqtt-subscription-realtime.${userID}`,
        auth: false,
        clean: true, // clean session YES deletes the queue when all clients disconnect
      }, connectionProps);

      /* create mqtt client */
      MQTT.createClient(this.conProps)
        .then((client) => {
          this.client = client;
          client.on('closed', this.onConnectionClosed);
          client.on('error', this.onError);
          client.on('message', this.onMessageArrived);
          client.on('connect', this.onConnectionOpened);
          client.connect();
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.error(`MQTT.createtClient error: ${err}`);
        });
    }
  },
   ...
  onMessageArrived(message) {
    if (message) {
      console.log(`MQTT New message: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`)
    }
  }
  ...
```

**Usage**

```js
import MqttNotificationsManager from './realtimeManager';

// init realtime
MqttNotificationsManager.create(
  'bob',
  {
    uri: 'mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883',
  },
);
```